# Usage of Big O for speedup comparison

Tags: big-o

From an (excellent) [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/58762/19553) at another SE site a statement was presented which I reacted on: "X is roughly O(10^4) times faster than Y".

From the context it was obvious that the meaning was something along the lines of "X is roughly 4 orders of magnitude faster than Y", but this got me thinking: What exactly does such a Big O statement mean? I was sure at first sight the two were not equivalent, but thinking about it I cannot get my head around what it means exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that asymptotically, X is either only faster than Y by a constant factor, or is *slower* than Y. (If it were big-Theta instead of big-O, it would unambiguously mean the first). As you've guessed, there's no real difference between `O(eight bazillion)` and `O(1)`; so what this is saying is "The factor by which X is faster than Y does not grow as the input grows". It may, however, *shrink*, hence the ambiguity I mentioned.

Obviously that literal meaning is not what the original poster intended. There's an unfortunate tendency to put `O()` around formulas when talking about performance when what the person really means is "give or take a little, I haven't literally benchmarked it".